# AlphaMaskFilter is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I believe I made a quite simple mistake but I stuck and couldn't solve it.

When I try to create and apply a filter with the following code, I am getting `TypeError: createjs.AlphaMaskFilter is not a constructor` error from Firebug Console for the 2nd line.

```
var worldMask = new createjs.Bitmap("world-mask.png");
var mask = new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(worldMask.image);
this.layers.world = new createjs.Bitmap("world.jpg");
this.layers.world.filters = [mask];
this.layers.world.cache(0, 0, worldMask.image.width, worldMask.image.height);
```

What I am trying to achieve is creating a transparent layer from a JPEG by masking it with a transparent PNG by the way.

**Solution :**

It seems EaselJS doesn't contain AlphaMaskFilter thing in the package. I've added it separately and voila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minified version of EaseJS doesn't include several filters, including `AlphaMaskFilter`. You have to include them yourself:

> EaselJS comes with a number of pre-built filters. **Note that individual filters are not compiled into the minified version of EaselJS**. To use them, you must include them manually in the HTML. [[source]](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Filter.html)

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that just after a few minutes after posted this question. But the reward goes to you anyway. =)

Comment: @Tim: Woops. In that case, post an answer to your own question and accept it. It works and provides answers to other people with the same problem. Don't edit the answer into your question, since this will leave the question opened. See also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/